# AQL include for multi value property returns only first value

Tags: artifactory, artifactory-query-lang

What's the right AQL format to include all values for a multi value property field.  Neither `@<prop name>` nor `properties.*` seem to work.

When running an AQL query and including a property field which contains multiple values the result contains the first value and not a list containing all values

```
items.find(...).include("*","@distro")
```

At present, I run one query to generate a list of artifacts and then iterate through the list running a query for each artifacts properties

```
f'/api/storage/{artifact.repo}/{artifact.path}/{artifact.name}?properties'
```

## Result

```
...properties {'key': 'distro', 'value': 'Ubuntu'}
```

## Desired Result

```
...properties {'key': 'distro', 'value': ['Ubuntu', 'CentOS',...]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I heard back from jfrog support and the problem seems to be that the use of '@propertyname' allows for the collapse of a potentially multi value property into a single value and this blocks the gathering of all properties.

A more efficient approach would be

```
items.find(...).include("property")
```

This results in all properties returned in the json payload as it includes the property *domain* which includes all the properties.

Additionally, by not using *@* the query doesn't collapse the properties from lists of values to a single value. So, if build_number is a property it becomes `['25']` instead of `25`.

When requesting the property domain, be sure to treat each property as a list.